# How do I wrap a group of HTML elements in a parent HTML element and keep them inside each parent with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to wrap all `span` tags within a `div` with another `div` via JavaScript or jQuery. I want to find any element with the class `wpb_wrapper` and then look for all `span` within it and then wrap the group in a single `div` within each `wpb_wrapper` so that each group of child `span` within any `wpb_wrapper` elements are still children, but wrapped in a `div` inside and not into a single `div` for every single `span` on the page.

From this:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this and it still just grabs all the `span` inside all `wpb_wrapper`s and just wraps it in a single `div` into the first `wpb_wrapper`

```
jQuery('.wpb_wrapper').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('span').wrapAll('<div class=""/>');
});
```

```js
jQuery('.wpb_wrapper').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('span').wrapAll('<div class=""/>');
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```css
.wpb_wrapper { border: 1px solid; }
.wpb_wrapper > div { border: 1px dotted red; }
.wpb_wrapper > div > span { border: 1px dashed blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class="">0</span>
  <span class="">0</span>
  <span class="">0</span>
  <span class="">0</span>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class="">1</span>
  <span class="">1</span>
  <span class="">1</span>
  <span class="">1</span>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <span class="">2</span>
  <span class="">2</span>
  <span class="">2</span>
  <span class="">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost. It takes every single span for every .wpb_wrapper and wraps them all into one div instead of being a child of each .wpb_wrapper

Comment: No, it doesn't. `wrapAll` wraps all of the elements in the specified jQuery object in a single HTML element. [Edit] your question to show how you tried to implement the answers to the suggested duplicate.

Comment: It does wrap them, but it takes every single `span` within every single `.wpb_wrapper` and just puts them all into just one `div` inside the first `.wpb_wrapper`

Comment: Again, it depends on how you implemented the code. You may need to get a jQuery object of all of `.wpb_wrapper` objects, iterate over them with `each` and call `$(this).find('span').wrapAll('<div></div>')`. If you just get a jQuery object that contains all of the spans in your document, of course it's going to wrap them all in a single element; that's what it does. It `wrap`s `All` of the elements given to it into an element.

Comment: I edited the question to explain it more. Using `each` still grabs all of the `span` in all parent `div`s and puts it only into one. I need each `span` group to stay within each of their parent `div`s

Comment: I've added a snippet showing the code works as intended; each `.wpb_wrapper` has its own child `<div class="">` that wraps the `<span>`s within each `.wpb_wrapper`.

Comment: I got it. I know what I did wrong. There was another parent class of `wpb_wrapper` and only looking for all `wpb_wrapper` was screwing everything up. It works now. So doing `each` on `.wpb_wrapper-parent .wpb_wrapper` and it works. All my fault. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wpb_wrapper');
  const spans = wrapper.querySelectorAll('span');

  const customDiv = document.createElement('div');
  customDiv.classList.add('custom-div');

  spans.forEach(span => {
    customDiv.appendChild(span);
  });

  wrapper.appendChild(customDiv);
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <h2><img decoding="async" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-9244" src="icon-briefcase.svg" alt="" width="24" height="24">Functional Experience</h2>
  <p></p>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
  <span class=""></span>
</div>
```

Pretty straight forward, we would just append the span element into a newly created div element. The catch however is that we're assuming we're appending this to the end of wgb_wrapper.